# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its view

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a splash screen for my app. When I try to change my imagesview property and set an animation I receive an error.

I have been tested runonuithread and Hadler, but in this 2 cases there is no error and  nothing is shown on the screen and after a delay(exactly what I specify in my code) program activity switches to the next activity this is my code:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    try {
            TranslateAnimation moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(500, 0, 0, 0);
            moveLefttoRight.setDuration(5000);
            moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(true);
            im.startAnimation(moveLefttoRight);//im is an image view
            SystemClock.sleep(6000);
            TranslateAnimation moveRighttoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 0);
            moveRighttoLeft.setDuration(1000);
            moveRighttoLeft.setFillAfter(true);
            im.startAnimation(moveRighttoLeft);
            SystemClock.sleep(6000);
            ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(0.3f, 1f, 0.3f, 1f, 
                    ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, 
                    ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);
            scale.setDuration(1000);
            scale.setFillAfter(true);
            // Wait given period of time or exit on touch

            sig.startAnimation(scale);//sig is an image view

            SystemClock.sleep(2000);

    }
```

How can I fix this strange error?

Comment: Your are trying to make changes in view out side of UI thread... You have to animate your ImageView inside UI thread not in your thread

Comment: i try ui thread there is no error but just show me a balck screen inested my images

Comment: Then you must check your code or post your code for help... and always remember that only UI thread can make changes in view

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code  and it has no issues. When you change any view you must do it on the UI/main thread. You can try the code I edited:

```
TranslateAnimation moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(500, 0, 0,
        0);
moveLefttoRight.setDuration(5000);
moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(true);
bt1.startAnimation(moveLefttoRight);// im is an image view

moveLefttoRight.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        doAnim2(); // do the next animation
    }
});
```

Comment: tanks my freind it's working my problem solved tank you so much